# Rpy2 (working with Dataframes) - How to solve the Python(NaN) and R(NA) conflict?

Tags: python, r, random-forest, rpy2

I have a pandas dataFrame: `result` with 2 columns.

`doy` (day_of_year: independent variable, values 1,2,3,....365).

`bookings` (dependent variable, 279 numeric values and 86 NaN values)

Please find a portion of the dataFrame below:

[image]

My goal is to impute the missing values using `R (randomForest::rfImpute)` for further spectral analysis.
So, I am using `rpy2` to use R-code inside Python script. I have imported necessary packages/libraries. I have also activated `pandas2ri.

```
import random
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
base = importr('base')
utils = importr('utils')

randomForest = importr('randomForest')

from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
pandas2ri.activate()


r_df = pandas2ri.py2ri(result)

type(r_df)
print(r_df.head())
print(base.summary(r_df))


random.seed(222)

result.imputed = randomForest.rfImpute('bookings', 'doy', data = r_df)`
```

But whenever I run the code, I get the error: `No NA values found in bookings.`

It's clear that the R code fails to interpret the missing values.

I have also tried to replace `NaN with NA` in the R dataFrame `r_df`,

```
robjects.r('r_df[is.nan(as.numeric(r_df))] = NA')
```

but when I run the code, I get the error: `object r_df is not found.`

Is there a way around this issue? As of now, I am a bit stuck and can't seem to find a helpful documentation.

Please find below some other outputs of separate lines of code.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

(...)

> ```
> robjects.r('r_df[is.nan(as.numeric(r_df))] = NA')
> ```
>
> but when I run the code, I get the error: object r_df is not found.

`r_df`is the name of a Python variable (name defined in your Python code), so embedded R does not know about it.

> Is there a way around this issue? As of now, I am a bit stuck and can't seem to find a helpful documentation.

What about this:
https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v2.9.x/html/robjects_rinstance.html#r-the-instance-of-r